# What's the purpose of defining a has_many and belongs_to relationship in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I'm not sure if I understand that point of explicitly defining a relationship using has_many and belongs_to. I am using Mongoid.

```
class Band
  include Mongoid::Document
  field: name, type: String
  has_many :members
end

class Member
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, type: String
  belongs_to :band
end
```

I understand that a member is part of a band and a band contains many members. But why couldn't I just define a string field in Member called "band_name" that stored the name of the band, which I could use to retrieve a member's corresponding band later from the database.

Or if I wanted to get the members of a band, couldn't I just do:

```
 Member.where(band_name => "Coldplay");
```

Answer (score 0):

`has_many` and `belongs_to` are two types of associations that Rails provides to define associations between models.

To see all types of Rails associations, I recommend you looking at the [official Rails documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-types-of-associations)

When you define the associations like this, Rails will automatically add the foreign keys to the correct table in the database which is one of the advantage of Rails when you follow the correct convention.

In short, the Active Record associations create a metric buttload of convenience methods. but, you can always write your own methods to fetch everything. But that is not the Rails Way.

#### Example:

`Band1` is a Band with id = 1
`Band2` is a Band with id = 2

if `A` and `B` members belong to `Band1`, then in the database, `members` table will have `band_id` value set to 1.

Comment: How would I explicitly specify which members are part of each band. If I use the has_many and belongs_to relationship and I have Two bands, Band1 and Band2, and four members, A, B, C, D, how do I specify that A and B belong to Band1 and C and D belong to Band 2. I can't find anything regarding initializing objects.

Comment: If you define the associations that way, then when you create your Bands and Members, your `Members` will have a `band_id` in it, using that you will know which `Band` it belongs to.

Comment: To explain your example, A and B Members will have the `band_id` of B `Band` s ID in the database. You don't have to initialize these. IDs will be auto generated when you create the `Member` and `Band` records.

Comment: But what if we wanted Member A and B to be part of Band 2. How do we explicitly define this

Comment: Just update the Member A and B recrod's `band_id` in the database. set `band_id` = 2 and save the record and it will belong to `Band2` now where `Band2` s ID = 2 in the `bands` table.